# What do you call the piece of clothing George Washington is wearing?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

What is the piece of clothing slung around George Washington's legs and right arm called?

[image: Statue of Washington]

Comment: There is a *sword* in his left hand. The sword is in a *sheath*.

Comment: @Silenus left from our side not his:)

Comment: You can probably get away with calling is a *toga*.

Comment: Thanks.Something like ''old fashioned tunic" would be okay then.@Silenus

Comment: It's probably a [toga](http://static1.squarespace.com/static/54e34f7fe4b05ae6226de04e/t/55a44f14e4b0f37d3af53a39/1436831509442/?format=500w), with the sculptor making use of artistic licence. (Image courtesy of [david-decoteau.squarespace.com/competition/togatrot](http://david-decoteau.squarespace.com/competition/togatrot)).

Comment: What body part are you talking about here? Your title says leg (which one? — not that we can really see either of them); in the question body you say both left hand (that's a sword, not clothes) and lap (that looks like a toga). Could you be more clear?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet apologies for my vagueness.But thanks for the right answer!

Comment: @agga His left hand is always his left hand, regardless of whose point of view you're talking about. And there's nothing on his right hand at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  The OP certainly means GW's right hand.  He's got to edit. It should be "right arm".

Comment: Didn't realise Washington was so ripped. How did he find the time to hit the gym so often?

Comment: @mgb He probably got that way cutting down all those cherry trees!

Comment: @BoldBen I had forgotten his eco-vandalism, alongside his leading a bunch of terrorists.

Comment: @mgb Can't have been terrorists because they won. Surely that's the main difference between 'terrorists' and 'freedom fighters'.

Comment: I'm sure that old George "Please Don't Make Me an Emperor" Washington would have loved being depicted as a god.

Comment: George Washington didn't deliberately target Tory civilians, burn down their homes, torture prisoners, rape women, or round up British loyalists and have mass executions. No, he wasn't a terrorist. It has to do with tactics, not whether he was the winner or the loser.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For this sculpture, Horatio Greenough was inspired by The [Statue of Zeus at Olympia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statue_of_Zeus_at_Olympia) that was a giant seated figure, about 13 m (43 ft) tall, made by the Greek sculptor Phidias around 435 BC at the sanctuary of Olympia.

The tunic worn by Zeus is a **himation**, a garment consisting of a rectangular piece of cloth thrown over the left shoulder and wrapped about the body. It seems that, for George Washington statue, the artist took some liberty by putting the garment on the right shoulder!

[image: Statue]

*Marble statue of Zeus showing himation being worn. Dresden -Staatliche Kunstsammlungen, Skulptureensammlung 68*.

*Engraving from a work of Antoine Chrysostome Quatremère de Quincy
(Le Jupiter olympien ou l'art de la sculpture antique)*.

Comment: did he take liberty or were the only pictures he had of one mirrored? :)

Comment: @jwenting - Mirroring was an unlikely possibility. Then, you forced me to check [web images](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Horatio+Greenough+george+washington&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMk4jF45vPAhVFOxoKHSAgAbUQ_AUICCgB&biw=1280&bih=904) :(

Comment: How do you pronounce this? I'm confused by "**an** himation"

Comment: @Brad - The word is so uncommon that I just read it and never heard it. So I don't know if the "h" is usually pronounced or not. But, most dictionaries mention "hi-mat-ee-on" as phonetic transcription. I edited my response accordingly.

Comment: @Graffito I did wonder whether he might have been working from a photo printed through the back of the negative, but then I found that the statue (made in the 1830s) predates Fox Talbot's negative/positive process but not the daguerrotype process invented by Niécephore Niepce which was very new and did reverse images if no mirror was introduced between the lens and the metal plate on which the image was formed. If Greenhough did work from a daguerrotype he could well have been working from a reversed image.